# How can I use Razor to send BLOB fileContent to my SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor, azure-web-app-service

As the question states, I have two buttons on a web page. One opens a file dialog when clicked and allows the user to a select a CSV from their documents. The second is supposed to send the file content and a few other parameters to an Azure SQL Server. All of this is running on ASP.NET Web App within Azure Web Services. My code is below, I have tried it and I can't tell if it is registering at all, I get no output to the console and no record in my database. Any help would be greatly appreciated! (EDIT: Of course, "" in the sqlConnection is where my connection string lies)

Here is what I tried:

```
@using System.Data.SqlClient;
<form>
    <!-- HTML -->
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    }

   
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display:none;" />
        <button id="selectFileButton">Select File</button>
        <label id="fileNameLabel" style="margin-left:10px;"></label>
        <button id="uploadButton">Upload</button>
    </body>

</form>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        // JavaScript
        document.querySelector("#selectFileButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.querySelector("#fileInput").click();
        });

        document.querySelector("#fileInput").addEventListener("change", function () {
            var file = document.querySelector("#fileInput").files[0];
            document.querySelector("#fileNameLabel").innerText = file.name;
        });

        document.querySelector("#uploadButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
            var file = document.querySelector("#fileInput").files[0];
            if (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    var parameters = {
                        data: reader.result,
                        fileName: file.name
                    };
                    Upload(parameters);
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            }
        });

      @{

    void Upload(string fileName, byte[] fileContent)
    {
          try
        {
            // Use a SqlCommandBuilder to send the data to SQL Server
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(""))
            {           
                var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT BLOBS ON INSERT INTO BLOBS (BatchID, CustomerNumber, CSV, DataType) VALUES (@BatchID, @CustomerNumber, @CSV, @DataType) SET IDENTITY_INSERT BLOBS OFF", sqlConnection);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerNumber", "9002");
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CSV", fileContent);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataType", "TestASP");
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchID", 61);
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while uploading to the database: " + ex.Message);
    
}
    }
}

      
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an SQL Database in Azure.

[image]

2. Created a table -`tblContent`  in Database of azure.

[image]

using the below code able to connect the database and able to insert data into the table.

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblContent VALUES (@Id,@Content)", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", 3);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", readText);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your answer, if you look at my code you might be able to see I have tried your described approach however for some reason I get no records. When I use the same method in a C# winforms app in VisualStudio, it works, so I am thinking it has something to do with my Javascript on my web app. Any suggestions?

Comment: The "Upload" method requires two parameters, "fileName" and "fileContent", but it is being passed only one parameter "parameters" in the "Upload" function call in the JavaScript code.

And the "ExecuteNonQuery" method of the SqlCommand object is not surrounded by a "sqlConnection.Open()" and "sqlConnection.Close()" statement or using a "using" block. The database connection should be opened before executing the command and closed after execution.